# Can I know from inside a subtable to which parent's key belongs directly while created?

Tags: lua, lua-table

It just passed through my mind and now I'm curious, so... Let's say I have this:

```
RL_Test.src = {}
RL_Test.src[1] = {["d"] = {["ID"] = 1, ["name"] = "NAME1"}}
RL_Test.src[2] = {["d"] = {["ID"] = 2, ["name"] = "NAME2"}}
```

Do you think there could be a way to set the value of the subtable's entries "ID" automatically accordingly to the key numbers of the table they belong directly? I mean, without having to parse/loop through the parent table or anything like that. I don't see the way and surely is for a good reason... but just wondering if it could be achieved by mean of one of those Lua tricks or something I'm missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are filling `RL_Test.src` with consequtive integer indices, you can just get its length:

```
RL_Test.src = {}
RL_Test.src[#RL_Test.src + 1] = {["d"] = {["ID"] = #RL_Test.src + 1, ["name"] = "NAME1"}}
RL_Test.src[#RL_Test.src + 1] = {["d"] = {["ID"] = #RL_Test.src + 1, ["name"] = "NAME2"}}
```

Comment: This will even work with non-consecutive integer indices (e.g. if some entries are deleted later on): `#RL_Test.src + 1` is always guaranteed to be `nil` so you can insert a value there.

Comment: Of course, the length operator! I don't know why I didn't think about that, but the case is I didn't... so thank you very much for showing me the way!

Comment: @Luatic Oh, but in such cases... couldn't you end up inserting items in unexpected positions along the table? I mean, if for whatever reason an entry was deleted not using `table.remove` (which ensures no gaps) and, thus, a gap was generated at some point in the middle of the array, `#RL_Test.src + 1` will target that gap instead of the end of the table and the item would be inserted there instead, isn't it? Not a problem I'm going to face in this case cause I don't even expect having to remove items but, assuming I'm right, maybe something to take into account just case? Thanks too!

Comment: @Rai if you're managing an *unordered* set, this doesn't matter. `#RL_Test.src + 1` *may* target that gap (it might as well target the end of the array). Inserting there won't overwrite anything.

Comment: @Luatic Yeah, no overwrites and, independently of anything, main table index is always going to match with the assigned inner table ID by using this method, which is great and, of course, the most important point. But what I attempted to puntualice is if, for whatever reason, you expect the newest addition is always going to be the very last in the main table list, it may not be the case should a gap exist due to a previous deletion not using `table.remove`. It'd hardly represent a problem &, in any case, nothing one can't solve, just may be taken into account in some cases (I guess). Cheers!